# Updating LaTeX packages in BaKoMa TeX

Tags: bakoma

Is there a way I can automatically update packages that come preloaded with `BaKoMa TeX` similar to `MiKTeX`? I can download the packages that I want to update from `CTAN` and replace the corresponding package folders; however, I was wondering if there is a way to automate this process.

Comment: http://www.bakoma-tex.com/menu/support.php

Comment: @HenriMenke, I have asked this question on their support page as well. I posted it here because it's relatively quicker to get response on Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Ashirwad Stack Exchange is usually rather fast, however there are not many BaKoMa TeX users here so I'm not sure you will get a good response to this.

Comment: @Marijn, yeah, that's true. I was just trying my luck!